# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.1.0 and No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1.0

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, pipenv

I am trying to use 'pipenv' on Windows Subsystem for Linux (ubuntu 18.04)
When I run

```
$ pipenv sync
```

I am getting this error :

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
tensorflow==2.1.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-gy0uz1a7-requirements/pipenv-glre38t7-requirement.txt (line 1))
(from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1.0 
(from -r /tmp/pipenv-gy0uz1a7-requirements/pipenv-glre38t7-requirement.txt (line 1))']
```

I followed some other instructions that say I have to install tensorflow, so I installed tensorflow

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
$ pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```

Even after installing tensorflow 2.1.0 I am still getting the same error when I run

```
$ pipenv sync
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your python version, the python 3.8 doesn't support TensorFlow 2.1 version.